# Can't make my header responsive table sticky

Tags: angular, html-table, sticky

I'm using angular 6 and i want to make my responsive table header sticky when i scroll, the problem is when i make it sticky the width of my header table are not the same of my columns cause of responsive.

I couldn't do work the position : sticky on my  so i tried with a angular module https://w11k.github.io/angular-sticky-things/
I also tried to do it by own in Jquery but the same result as the module cause it's changed the position to fixed...

```
<div class="table-responsive" #spacer *ngIf="deals?.list?.length">
<table [style.width.%]="100" >
<mng-sort-thead >
<tr style="background-color:white;position:sticky"  >
  <th
    *ngFor="let column of columns" (click)="sort(column.key)">
    {{ column.titleTable }}
  </th>
</tr>
 </mng-sort-thead>
 <tbody class="mt-15">
<tr *ngFor="let item of deals.list">
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Do someone know why the position:stciky doesn't work on  ?
Or a way to my header table keep the width of my columns ?
Thanks

Comment: refer this: https://medium.com/@elad/css-position-sticky-how-it-really-works-54cd01dc2d46

Comment: Do my table header will keep the same size after getting sticky ?
Reading the topics seems it's a container problem.